# Condition with pass statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to figure out how to check if line contains some substrings or not, if it does, print that string. If it doesn't, do nothing. For this do nothing thing, I found that there is a statement in Python that just holds space and does nothing, which is `pass` so I used it. but the result is all strings are being printed no matter the condition.

```
try:
  string = line.split(',')
  if string[0] != 'Aa' or string[0] != 'Bb':
    pass
  print string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `print string` line is independent of the if-statement.  Meaning, it will be executed regardless of whether or not your condition is true.

You would need an `else:` block to do what you want:

```
string = line.split(',')
if string[0] != 'Aa' and string[0] != 'Bb': # You need 'and' up here
  pass
else:
  print string # This will only be executed if the condition is false
```

But that is somewhat redundant.  A better approach would be to just do:

```
string = line.split(',')
if string[0] == 'Aa' or string[0] == 'Bb':
  print string
```

or maybe:

```
string = line.split(',')
if string[0] in {'Aa', 'Bb'}:
  print string
```

Answer (score 4):

Just this:

```
string = line.split(',')
if string[0] == 'Aa' or string[0] == 'Bb':
    print string
```

You don't need `pass`

Answer (score 2):

`try/except` is for error handling. I don't think you'll need it for this purpose.

`string=line.split(',')` is correct. It'll split the string into a list of strings according to commas.

The problem is `print string`. It's not inside the scope of the `if` statement, so the `if` statement has no effect on printing the string. You'll want something like this:

```
if string[0] != 'Aa' or string[0] != 'Bb':
    pass
else:
    print string
```

or better yet:

```
if string[0] == 'Aa' or string[0] == 'Bb':
    print string
```